# asp mvc - Setting application's cookies as secured

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm working on an asp-mvc application and want to set all the cookies with secured attributes. I read similar threads and have added the following in my web config:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

Also created an HttpModule, which I have registered via web config and implemented it as follows:
I've checked in debug and each request it gets to the OnApplicationBeginRequest and OnApplicationEndRequest code.

```
 public class SecureSessionModule : IHttpModule
{


    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnApplicationBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
    }

    void OnApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest currentRequest = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;
        HttpCookie requestCookie = RetrieveRequestCookie(currentRequest, "ASP.NET_SessionId");

        if (requestCookie != null)
        {
            requestCookie.Secure = true;
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest currentRequest = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;

        HttpCookie sessionCookie = RetrieveResponseCookie(((HttpApplication)sender).Response, "ASP.NET_SessionId");

        if (sessionCookie != null)
        {
            sessionCookie.Secure = true;
        }
    }

 private HttpCookie RetrieveResponseCookie(HttpResponse currentResponse, string cookieName)
    {
        HttpCookieCollection cookies = currentResponse.Cookies;
        return FindTheCookie(cookies, cookieName);
    }

    private HttpCookie FindTheCookie(HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection, string cookieName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookieCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(cookieCollection[i].Name, cookieName, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                return cookieCollection[i];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now, I've opened fiddler and in the request:

```
Request sent 42 bytes of Cookie data:

ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
and that's it
```

In response, "This response did not set any cookies".

It seems that the application ignores all my setting. Any sugestions, please?

Comment: How did you actually register this http module on with webconfig?

Comment: @misha130
  <httpModules>
      <add type= "SecureSessionModule" name="SecureSessionModule" />
    </httpModules>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);` after altering the cookie. Just changing cookie values does not put the cookie to response.